# measure influence of road features on crash incidents: regression or factor analysis?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, modeling, factor-analysis

I am a statistics newbie who made the poor choice of having a statistician on my thesis committee. He expects me to run stats on a large dataset of traffic accidents and their associated features (time of day, road condition, speed limit, etc.) to determine which factors significantly contribute to crash occurrence. Each row is a crash incident and each column contains descriptives about that particular incident. I am having some trouble figuring out what my dependent variable is, since I already know a crash has occurred at each datapoint. Of course all the crash factors are independent variables. I have been Googling like a madwoman, but jargon makes it hard for me to understand. Can someone give feedback and guidance on how I should proceed? Being that I am a newbie, I plan to use Stata or SPSS. My data is a mix of categorical and numerical (discrete).
It seems like I need to begin by running a number of descriptive stat tests to determine baseline knowledge. Any tips on what that might be? I am also unsure of what kind of regression (I am assuming I should be looking at regression analysis) tool to run. I am trying to wrap my head around this paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep37300 which seems to model what I'd like to do. It's a bit over my head, though.

It seems like I have all the components for a multiple linear regression (which is the outcome I'd like: an equation with corresponding beta values and significance levels) EXCEPT my independent variable is static (i.e. ALL data points are fatal crashes, I just want to know which road features are most impactful!) What can I do? I am confused 
SOS, please help

Comment: A quick look at the referenced article shows that it uses monthly number of traffic incidents, i.e., a dependent variable with variation.  You seem to have a real conundrum and it's probably not what you want to hear but you may need to hire a statistical consultant--or change your research questions--or obtain a new dataset :-(

Comment: Thanks for this perspective! I was trying to figure out if they did have a continuous dependent variable on that study. I am going to rack my mind and try, try again. It seems like the search for a statistical method that fits my data is more difficult than actually changing my data!

Comment: Do you have map coordinates of the crashes? Then I would start by plotting them on a map. Or, what you have could be seen as a kind of (multidimensional) point process, so maybe look into that, and estimate an intensity function?

Comment: The linked paper looks at meteorological conditions as explanatory variables. They will vary with time, so it makes sense to count number of crashes per day&location.  But you want to look at *road conditions*, maybe invariant in time? (or do they include such as wetness/slippery/friction?) Divide the roads in parts with the same conditions, (amybe also in time intervals with same conditions), for each such cluster, count the number of incidents (including zero incidents!), calculare some measure of trafic*time which you can use for an offset in a count data regression model.